# Yii2 using authclient for facebook and google login not working

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user, yii2-authclient

Sorry people, I'm really new in Yii2 framework!!

I'm trying to do a web login using "yiisoft/yii2-authclient" at version 2.2.14
After client autentication, nothing happen and the new user is not logged in and the auth table is empty

I state that I created a new module /common/modules/user/ModuleUser.php and instead of handle the auth action in SiteController I do it in /common/modules/user/controllers/DefaultController.php in where I placed all the user actions such as login, logout and so on.

I set behaviours() to allow access to each those action

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::class,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'auth',...],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
    ],
],
```

I set action and callback in this way

```
'auth' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
    'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess']
],
```

```
public function onAuthSuccess($client)
{
    (new AuthHandler($client))->handle();
}
```

It seems this **onAuthSuccess()** function is never called.

Procedure starts at `/user/default/auth?authclient=facebook|google`

Both clients, facebook and google, on user succefully autenticated, bounce to the correct redirect url
`/user/default/auth?authclient=facebook&code=AQDxqg....`
but nothing happens,  and it seems successCallback is not invoked, no errors occurred, even on apache level.

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong...
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, I made so stupid mistake while moving files in common/modules/user/:
I forgot to adjust namespace into class AuthHandler, and some other little mess with "use" declarations for that class...